# How to fix this? I get when importaing a .sql file.[#Error1044]

Tags: mysql

Error
SQL query:

```
--
-- БД: `mlrp`
--
CREATE DATABASE IF NOT EXISTS `mlrp` DEFAULT CHARACTER SET latin1 COLLATE latin1_swedish_ci;
```

MySQL said: Documentation

> #1044 - Access denied for user 'vfwx10mx'@'localhost' to database 'mlrp'

Comment: Do you connect from localhost?

Answer (score 0):

you need that root user will grant privileges to this user. 
look for what you need in here:
http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/grant.html

So use this:

```
GRANT ALL ON mlrp.* TO 'vfwx10mx'@'localhost';
```